# bootsrap 3 container-fluid only on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I have `<div class="container-full">` on desktop, but this class should be replaced with `<div class="container-fluid">` on mobile.

Thing is that container-full have some weird right padding on iOS devices and container-fluid does not. But I need container-full for desktop version.

Anyhow I believe this could be achieved with some jquery but I can't find good one.

thank you

Comment: Instead you can write media query for mobile devices and update css for the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you can do like this

```
 if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        $('div.container-full').addClass('container-fluid').removeClass('container-full');
    }
```

or like this

```
if(screen.width < 800 /*some amount that should be a mobile's phone screen width probably*/ ){
  $('div.container-full').addClass('container-fluid').removeClass('container-full');
}
```

Comment: You should not use userAgent for this kind of things: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent, https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/09/user-agent-detection-history-and-checklist/

Answer (score 3):

You should try to add a media query like @Sahil commented:
(Add the overwriting class after fluid or full)

```
// max-width: 768px (xs) max-width: 992px (md)
   @media(max-width: 992px) {
        .container-full-and-fluid {
            padding: 0px !important;
        }
   }
```